# Fastest way to check if a url exists

Tags: ruby, url, optimization

currently I am writing a program that needs to check tons of possible urls searching for any that actually exist. To be precise, I mean exist as in you can visit the url and there's actual content of some sort.. not string parsing to see if it's in url format.

The program generates a list of possible variants for a filename and then checks each one until it gets a url that actually exists, so most of the url remains the same. Examples would be,

```
https://www.test.com/folder1/FILE.png
https://www.test.com/folder1/File.png
https://www.test.com/folder1/file.png
https://www.test.com/folder1/file1.png
```

That said, my code currently works fine.. however it ends up taking about 2-4 secods per url check and I don't know of a way to speed it up. Is there any faster or better way to validate urls or am I just out of luck?

This is my function to validate urls:

```
require "net/http"

def url_exist? url_path
  url = URI.parse(url_path)
  req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  req.use_ssl = true
  res = req.request_head(url.path)
 
  if res.code == "200" || res.code == "403"
    return true
  end
end
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. I don't know the answer to your question, but I thought I'd just mention that it's idiomatic in Ruby to return a boolean value from methods whose name ends with "?".

Comment: What is the likelihood that you will be repeating the `url_exist?` method for the same url? If that is likely, you could cache the result and avoid a request. However you would also need to deal with cache expiry, else you might be using stale data.

Comment: @LesNightingill So, the exact url path would never be repeated, however I'll ellaborate more on what this project does in case maybe what you said still applies. url_exist? would only be ran once per complete url path.. however all of the urls being checked are slight variants and otherwise ALMOST the same.

Comment: @LesNightingill 
The project generates a whole bunch of variants of a url in the hopes of guessing the correct one (one that actually exists). Examples would be..

```
https://www.test.com/folder1/FILE.png
https://www.test.com/folder1/File.png
https://www.test.com/folder1/file.png
https://www.test.com/folder1/FILE1.png
```

And so on. Could cacheing possibly be used for the consistent parts of the urls?

Comment: I don't think caching will work because if the endpoint is different at all, you'll still need to make another http request.

Comment: Do you have a real example of URLs you are checking? Have you actually found any?  Not sure what's slowing you down here. But only other thing I might suggest is to multi-thread this method? Also last line of your method could simply be `res.code == "200" || res.code == "403"` and the if/end part can be removed as that alone will return true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Your code creates a new connection for each URL. It should be faster to send multiple requests over the same connection via [HTTP keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

In Ruby, you can open such connection via [`Net::HTTP.start`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#start-method), e.g.:

```
require 'net/http'

class URLChecker
  def initialize(base_url)
    uri = URI(base_url)
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.is_a?(URI::HTTPS)) do |http|
      @http = http
      yield self
    end
  end

  def exist?(path)
    res = @http.head(path)
    res.code == '200' || res.code == '403'
  end
end

URLChecker.new('https://stackoverflow.com') do |uc|
  p uc.exist?('/questions/tagged/ruby')   #=> true
  p uc.exist?('/questions/tagged/python') #=> true
  p uc.exist?('/questions/tagged/foobar') #=> false
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That did speed up the process a bit more than what I was doing, although I think I've figured out the problem. In the examples you gave and for other common websites.. it's almost instant to check all of the urls. The site I'm using them on however, I think is just slow to handle requests as it takes a lot longer.